# Многоуровневое меню и граница окна браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, меню

Все мы помним многоуровневые меню где есть 3-4 уровня вложенности. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать, кто и как борется с адаптивностью при приближении границы браузера? Например, если сделать 2 выпадающих уровня у крайнего пункта списка, то получим прокрутку или просто обрезанное меню.

Правильно ли использовать скрипты, для определения нахождения меню внутри видимой области экрана и существует ли вообще такая практика?

Comment: А почему не правильно? Покажите CSS и HTML, и если там скрипт используется, то и его киньте. Вам помогут написать скрипт :)

Comment: Просто высчитывается это скриптом, не css. На кодепене можно поискать такое адаптивное меню с такой логикой, я видел.

Comment: @Yuri вопрос не в помощи и реализации. Это я без труда осилю. Вопрос в правильности. Подобне решения в сети практически не встречаются, поэтому и созрел вопрос. Дело в каких-то подводных камнях? Или просто никто не заморачивается? Возможно прокрутку видят поисковики и ругаются, так как изменения вносятся скриптом. От этого и вопрос возник.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, таким образом работает меню на microsoft, google, apple сайтах. Хотя способ довольно древний. Я им ещё в 2011 пользовался :)

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, хотя можно сделать на чистом CSS. Только там придётся писать кучу логически сложных уравнений :)

Comment: @Yuri не припоминаю у Apple вообще таких выпадашек. Если способ древний, то что сейчас актуально? Кроме простых одноуровневых меню или выпадающий список со 100% шириной? По поводу уравнений, `calc` сейчас до сих пор в немилости у W3C. Можно еще поиграться с EQCSS, но это ж все равно подключение библиотеки внешней.